# Best rated apps ? Any list of them?

Tags: google-play-store

Thousands of apps on playstore but there is no way to sort them on best rated.is there any site of way to find best rated apps (from playstore or otherwise) ???

Comment: Such ordering would've been useless to separate the cream from the crop. The best rated app is the app that is rated by 5-star by one person.

Comment: I agree with Lie: sorting on rating alone is insufficient. [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/) has its own rating system (0..100 points), taking additional criteria into consideration – but I couldn't yet figure out how to sort by that. To my experience, some "low rated" apps are better than many "high rated" in the same category. If you're looking for a hand-picked selection, you're welcome to see [my lists](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php) – but it's far from being complete, and never will be (currently ~9.000 apps are listed there).

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Summing up from the comments:</sup>

To my knowledge, there's no site currently which has a complete records of all available apps (not even that, I'm afraid), or at least the most of them, and really allows you to sort by ratings. As [Lie Ryan](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/482/lie-ryan) pointed out in the first comment on the question, this wouldn't even be very useful: A dev could simply ask his "best friend" to rate his crap app 5-stars. As long as nobody else rates it, that would turn out on top of the "best list". And to my own experience, some "average rated" apps are better than their "high rated" competitors. It always depends on what *you* need them for, what your requirements and expectations are. Those might differ from the "big swarm" ;)

So you would need additional criteria. [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/) somehow set up its own rating system of "100 points max". I'm not sure about the real formula, but it seems to take into consideration how long an app is out. Though: *AppBrain* doesn't really enable you to list all apps by rating.

If you're happy with a smaller, hand-picked list of apps, I can recommend you my own site: **[my app lists](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php)** are separated into "real life categories" (no such things like "productivity", whatever that should be – but rather e.g. "eMail Apps", "File Managers", etc.), which have their related apps ordered by... yes. Rating and votes, descending. That is: Highest ratings first, and if two apps are rated similar, the one with the most votes comes first. Far from being perfect, though. But you find them linked with additional information, such as reviews, demo videos, etc; so when looking for a "good app for X", that should be a pretty nice starting point :) But be aware it has only about 1% of the apps from Google Play, and doesn't cover all areas (e.g. almost no "social network" stuff, games, or sports).